# How to change the name of a filed in a POJO class without Jackson or GSON?

Tags: java, android

I want to map the properties that are coming from a back-end server with the correct names. This is my class:

```
public class Repository {
    public String full_name;
}
```

And I want to use it as `fullName` **not** `full_name`. How to achieve this without any library? Is this even possible? Thnaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need a library, but you have to add the annotation `@SerializedName` before each attribute declaration.

For Example:

```
public class Repository {

   @SerializedName("full_name")
   public String fullName;

   public void setFullName(String fullName){
        this.fullName=fullName;
   }
   public void getFulltName(){
        treturn firstName;
   }

 }
```

User [RoboPOJOGenerator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8634-robopojogenerator) for generating pojo from your json on Android Studio.

**Manual Parsing:**

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject("your_json_string");
Repository repository=new Repository();
repository.setFullName(json.optString("full_name"));
```

**Note :** You no need to add `@SerializedName` in class attribute declaration for manual parsing

Comment: There is no way to achieve this without a library?

Comment: You can with manual parsing but it's will slow and too much code need to add

Comment: Please provide me an example. I'm having only one field in my class, `full_name`. Please edit your answer and show me how. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks but I don't get it. How is your code changing the field from `full_name` to `fullName`? When using `@SerializedName` it is mandatory to use GSON library.

Comment: `@SerializedName` mandatory if you are not used same name (case sensitive) for class attribute

Comment: Ok but you did not answer my question. How do I change the name without any library?

Comment: you can't change the name . the name should be as it is the Json response (or as you documentation says)

Comment: I can achieve this with manual parsing but **not** without a library. Anyway, thanks for your efforts.